# RSA decryption fine with encoded byte array but fails with encoded String [IllegalBlockSizeException]

Tags: java, arrays, string, exception, rsa

we are trying RSA Encryption & Decryption and the issue happens while decrypting. This is our decryption code

```
Cipher oaepFromInit = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding");
OAEPParameterSpec oaepParams = new OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-1", "MGF1", new MGF1ParameterSpec("SHA-1"), PSpecified.DEFAULT);
oaepFromInit.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, rsaPrivateKey, oaepParams);
byte[] dec = oaepFromInit.doFinal(encrytpedData.getBytes());
```

The `encrytpedData` is like this

```
s11Pyj5rrVOfOiWtxpGq+K5D+pYi16CyyX/EwKfMErBkHJ4aVlTmnhrfeCS7LEeXgTs3gkFp96I/oTedG/rXxF2hTAmMH40k0joKJbRtzO858/0dcaaE1uNzr/rI0Jj3ebXPLGhefCMNNpyFH5V4ukVo6vtev5Z9U8oNkUQolbX/r5jJJomkKCCnzGoHMdQg5dafj9Sw/qakO13501YBrkxS0i9ca0GZ8Ll42NwkOZuInh+MAu+gYW4vAr284eJsqgLgTp0+MS1tmfwR6EXgspk1nYR/U84P3MBZAdpmD3nxsVV3iVOCUeoqVyd4kw7M2pvXev6hMbMN4P1nnomo8g==
```

An error exception was thrown saying `javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Data must not be longer than 256 bytes`

We looked into this link [getting a IllegalBlockSizeException: Data must not be longer than 256 bytes when using rsa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007147/getting-a-illegalblocksizeexception-data-must-not-be-longer-than-256-bytes-when), but the issue was with the way we were feeding the `encrytpedData`.

This is a code we got online

```
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
kpg.initialize(2048);
KeyPair kp = kpg.generateKeyPair();
RSAPublicKey pubkey = (RSAPublicKey) kp.getPublic();
RSAPrivateKey privkey = (RSAPrivateKey) kp.getPrivate();
        
// --- encrypt given algorithm string
Cipher oaepFromAlgo = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-1AndMGF1Padding");
oaepFromAlgo.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubkey);
byte[] ct = oaepFromAlgo.doFinal("chakka".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

// --- decrypt given OAEPParameterSpec
Cipher oaepFromInit = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding");
OAEPParameterSpec oaepParams = new OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-1", "MGF1", new MGF1ParameterSpec("SHA-1"), PSpecified.DEFAULT);
oaepFromInit.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privkey, oaepParams);
byte[] pt = oaepFromInit.doFinal(ct);
System.out.println("Printing decoded string");
System.out.println(new String(pt, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Here they are supplying the encrypted array directly and works fine, but in our case we are getting `encrytpedData` as String. Both the codes are same but the supply of encrypted data differs.

```
byte[] dec = oaepFromInit.doFinal(encrytpedData.getBytes());
```

This is where we are getting the exception, so we tried converting the `encrytpedData` to `byte[]` in a different way via these two links

1. [RSA encyrption - converting between bytes array and String [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43325310/rsa-encyrption-converting-between-bytes-array-and-string)
2. [IllegalBlockSizeException when trying to encrypt and decrypt a string with AES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30383736/illegalblocksizeexception-when-trying-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-a-string-with-aes)

So we tried like this

1. `byte[] dec = oaepFromInit.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encrytpedData));` which resulted in this `javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Message is larger than modulus`.
2. `byte[] dec = oaepFromInit.doFinal(encrytpedData.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));` which gave the same old exception `javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Data must not be longer than 256 bytes`.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The encrypted data is obviously Base64 encoded, so solution 1 with Base64 decoding should be correct. Base64 decoded the data has a length of 256 bytes or 2048 bits, which corresponds to a 2048 bits key. Does your key have this size? Maybe the private and the public key do not match. Also the padding and in case of OAEP the OAEP parameters on both sides must be the same. Have you checked that? What does the encryption code look like (probably not the one you've posted, since this code doesn't Base64 encode the ciphertext)?

Comment: I'm really sorry @Topaco, actually the step-1 was the right way, but we had the old public & private key. I'm sorry for wasting your time, I'll close this question as a duplicate to the Step-1 link.

Answer (score 1):

The below full example code is taken from my private cross-platform project and should work. It encrypts a string using **RSA encryption with a 2048 key** pair and uses **OAEP padding with SHA-1** as hash.

The encrypted data are in base64 encoding. For demonstration purpose I'm using **static (hardcoded) keys in PEM-format - never ever do this in production**.

You can run the code online here: https://repl.it/@javacrypto/CpcJavaRsaEncryptionOaepSha1String

this is the output:

```
RSA 2048 encryption OAEP SHA-1 string
plaintext: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

* * * encrypt the plaintext with the RSA public key * * *
ciphertextBase64: pSPayOK79NMPLpaQOp8L7dOTdLeS+jVU5cKPF5mDOvuKtnOjf/NYfgsf1JWa5Ud/fzsXrSN8I/8KAs/freagOYflv6PGUHZ7cYk1iX6sO5cmdD0Mfglj39NxczbqCK3FG20hQfa01ZaOu/dV8+QvVx851ph1nEl8arNML5ohhjIdZTxR3olGouGzDJmuJkDlv2fJICP7sdMnvl7t21QI701I2xR01eatD5src5fY//EIOEjSoTesCBZwEUz1S3UpclNqGONAqaYqlscdTyAlY3Hg8smJRqKWk7ZWKSTYsocBbFeTvcNy75LG/xyILM0l4U+NnwGUypkjR2vJRGVQtw==

* * * decrypt the ciphertext with the RSA private key * * *
ciphertextReceivedBase64: pSPayOK79NMPLpaQOp8L7dOTdLeS+jVU5cKPF5mDOvuKtnOjf/NYfgsf1JWa5Ud/fzsXrSN8I/8KAs/freagOYflv6PGUHZ7cYk1iX6sO5cmdD0Mfglj39NxczbqCK3FG20hQfa01ZaOu/dV8+QvVx851ph1nEl8arNML5ohhjIdZTxR3olGouGzDJmuJkDlv2fJICP7sdMnvl7t21QI701I2xR01eatD5src5fY//EIOEjSoTesCBZwEUz1S3UpclNqGONAqaYqlscdTyAlY3Hg8smJRqKWk7ZWKSTYsocBbFeTvcNy75LG/xyILM0l4U+NnwGUypkjR2vJRGVQtw==
decryptedtext: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

**Security warning: the code does not have any exception handling, uses static (hardcoded) keys and is for educational purpose only.**

code:

```
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.OAEPParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PSource;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.spec.MGF1ParameterSpec;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        System.out.println("RSA 2048 encryption OAEP SHA-1 string");

        String dataToEncryptString = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
        byte[] dataToEncrypt = dataToEncryptString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        System.out.println("plaintext: " + dataToEncryptString);

        // # # # usually we would load the private and public key from a file or keystore # # #
        // # # # here we use hardcoded keys for demonstration - don't do this in real programs # # #
        String filenamePrivateKeyPem = "privatekey2048.pem";
        String filenamePublicKeyPem = "publickey2048.pem";

        // encryption
        System.out.println("\n* * * encrypt the plaintext with the RSA public key * * *");
        PublicKey publicKeyLoad = getPublicKeyFromString(loadRsaPublicKeyPem());
        // use this in production
        //PublicKey publicKeyLoad = getPublicKeyFromString(loadRsaKeyPemFile(filenamePublicKeyPem));
        String ciphertextBase64 = base64Encoding(rsaEncryptionOaepSha1(publicKeyLoad, dataToEncrypt));
        System.out.println("ciphertextBase64: " + ciphertextBase64);

        // transport the encrypted data to recipient

        // receiving the encrypted data, decryption
        System.out.println("\n* * * decrypt the ciphertext with the RSA private key * * *");
        String ciphertextReceivedBase64 = ciphertextBase64;
        //String ciphertextReceivedBase64 = "l4G3O42LtjI9KkzvcF7SQcpqrkOMJw1sWVuI3FCZ1g+Sp/t05E3ZEXyVV/FnadkKVgmpWBifaYPEdKNBTbuts2F1DfrDz1v14lKlMOcqkJB8OmJUAiKJ1ic414R7M5fECKruqkzOdKlTtdb3MI49Ygrzd/cJxOGEvONo3DAOq1kZvZdmyW+K8m807g2qoy833EHyj9NjVZHuDzXi8fMxbIAI5MrN8ykXZBxkFOAGiITEFbGPxu6gBOPJKsPWJ0SVU53CiI1YwGc76/ov4c7FIA1ZeVsJXKo8CEfYuUc7PKIJ3e5Z7CbiNgr4Z5720Xbi0drUBk/LlYq6m8s/zEIMaQ==";
        System.out.println("ciphertextReceivedBase64: " + ciphertextReceivedBase64);
        PrivateKey privateKeyLoad = getPrivateKeyFromString(loadRsaPrivateKeyPem());
        // use this in production
        //PrivateKey privateKeyLoad = getPrivateKeyFromString(loadRsaKeyPemFile(filenamePrivateKeyPem));
        byte[] ciphertextReceived = base64Decoding(ciphertextReceivedBase64);
        byte[] decryptedtextByte = rsaDecryptionOaepSha1(privateKeyLoad, ciphertextReceived);
        System.out.println("decryptedtext: " + new String(decryptedtextByte, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }

    public static byte[] rsaEncryptionOaepSha1 (PublicKey publicKey, byte[] plaintextByte) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
        byte[] ciphertextByte = null;
        Cipher encryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWITHSHA-1ANDMGF1PADDING");
        //OAEPParameterSpec oaepParameterSpecJCE = new OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-256", "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA256, PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT);
        // note: SHA1 is the default for Java
        OAEPParameterSpec oaepParameterSpecJCE = new OAEPParameterSpec("SHA1", "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA1, PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT);
        encryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey, oaepParameterSpecJCE);
        ciphertextByte = encryptCipher.doFinal(plaintextByte);
        return ciphertextByte;
    }

    public static byte[] rsaDecryptionOaepSha1 (PrivateKey privateKey, byte[] ciphertextByte) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
        byte[] decryptedtextByte = null;
        Cipher decryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWITHSHA-1ANDMGF1PADDING");
        //OAEPParameterSpec oaepParameterSpecJCE = new OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-256", "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA256, PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT);
        OAEPParameterSpec oaepParameterSpecJCE = new OAEPParameterSpec("SHA1", "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA1, PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT);
        decryptCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey, oaepParameterSpecJCE);
        decryptedtextByte = decryptCipher.doFinal(ciphertextByte);
        return decryptedtextByte;
    }

    private static String base64Encoding(byte[] input) {
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(input);
    }
    private static byte[] base64Decoding(String input) {
        return Base64.getDecoder().decode(input);
    }

    private static String loadRsaPrivateKeyPem() {
        // this is a sample key - don't worry !
        return "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n" +
                "MIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKgwggSkAgEAAoIBAQDwSZYlRn86zPi9\n" +
                "e1RTZL7QzgE/36zjbeCMyOhf6o/WIKeVxFwVbG2FAY3YJZIxnBH+9j1XS6f+ewjG\n" +
                "FlJY4f2IrOpS1kPiO3fmOo5N4nc8JKvjwmKtUM0t63uFFPfs69+7mKJ4w3tk2mSN\n" +
                "4gb8J9P9BCXtH6Q78SdOYvdCMspA1X8eERsdLb/jjHs8+gepKqQ6+XwZbSq0vf2B\n" +
                "MtaAB7zTX/Dk+ZxDfwIobShPaB0mYmojE2YAQeRq1gYdwwO1dEGk6E5J2toWPpKY\n" +
                "/IcSYsGKyFqrsmbw0880r1BwRDer4RFrkzp4zvY+kX3eDanlyMqDLPN+ghXT1lv8\n" +
                "snZpbaBDAgMBAAECggEBAIVxmHzjBc11/73bPB2EGaSEg5UhdzZm0wncmZCLB453\n" +
                "XBqEjk8nhDsVfdzIIMSEVEowHijYz1c4pMq9osXR26eHwCp47AI73H5zjowadPVl\n" +
                "uEAot/xgn1IdMN/boURmSj44qiI/DcwYrTdOi2qGA+jD4PwrUl4nsxiJRZ/x7PjL\n" +
                "hMzRbvDxQ4/Q4ThYXwoEGiIBBK/iB3Z5eR7lFa8E5yAaxM2QP9PENBr/OqkGXLWV\n" +
                "qA/YTxs3gAvkUjMhlScOi7PMwRX9HsrAeLKbLuC1KJv1p2THUtZbOHqrAF/uwHaj\n" +
                "ygUblFaa/BTckTN7PKSVIhp7OihbD04bSRrh+nOilcECgYEA/8atV5DmNxFrxF1P\n" +
                "ODDjdJPNb9pzNrDF03TiFBZWS4Q+2JazyLGjZzhg5Vv9RJ7VcIjPAbMy2Cy5BUff\n" +
                "EFE+8ryKVWfdpPxpPYOwHCJSw4Bqqdj0Pmp/xw928ebrnUoCzdkUqYYpRWx0T7YV\n" +
                "RoA9RiBfQiVHhuJBSDPYJPoP34kCgYEA8H9wLE5L8raUn4NYYRuUVMa+1k4Q1N3X\n" +
                "Bixm5cccc/Ja4LVvrnWqmFOmfFgpVd8BcTGaPSsqfA4j/oEQp7tmjZqggVFqiM2m\n" +
                "J2YEv18cY/5kiDUVYR7VWSkpqVOkgiX3lK3UkIngnVMGGFnoIBlfBFF9uo02rZpC\n" +
                "5o5zebaDImsCgYAE9d5wv0+nq7/STBj4NwKCRUeLrsnjOqRriG3GA/TifAsX+jw8\n" +
                "XS2VF+PRLuqHhSkQiKazGr2Wsa9Y6d7qmxjEbmGkbGJBC+AioEYvFX9TaU8oQhvi\n" +
                "hgA6ZRNid58EKuZJBbe/3ek4/nR3A0oAVwZZMNGIH972P7cSZmb/uJXMOQKBgQCs\n" +
                "FaQAL+4sN/TUxrkAkylqF+QJmEZ26l2nrzHZjMWROYNJcsn8/XkaEhD4vGSnazCu\n" +
                "/B0vU6nMppmezF9Mhc112YSrw8QFK5GOc3NGNBoueqMYy1MG8Xcbm1aSMKVv8xba\n" +
                "rh+BZQbxy6x61CpCfaT9hAoA6HaNdeoU6y05lBz1DQKBgAbYiIk56QZHeoZKiZxy\n" +
                "4eicQS0sVKKRb24ZUd+04cNSTfeIuuXZrYJ48Jbr0fzjIM3EfHvLgh9rAZ+aHe/L\n" +
                "84Ig17KiExe+qyYHjut/SC0wODDtzM/jtrpqyYa5JoEpPIaUSgPuTH/WhO3cDsx6\n" +
                "3PIW4/CddNs8mCSBOqTnoaxh\n" +
                "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----";
    }

    private static String loadRsaPublicKeyPem() {
        // this is a sample key - don't worry !
        return "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n" +
                "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA8EmWJUZ/Osz4vXtUU2S+\n" +
                "0M4BP9+s423gjMjoX+qP1iCnlcRcFWxthQGN2CWSMZwR/vY9V0un/nsIxhZSWOH9\n" +
                "iKzqUtZD4jt35jqOTeJ3PCSr48JirVDNLet7hRT37Ovfu5iieMN7ZNpkjeIG/CfT\n" +
                "/QQl7R+kO/EnTmL3QjLKQNV/HhEbHS2/44x7PPoHqSqkOvl8GW0qtL39gTLWgAe8\n" +
                "01/w5PmcQ38CKG0oT2gdJmJqIxNmAEHkatYGHcMDtXRBpOhOSdraFj6SmPyHEmLB\n" +
                "ishaq7Jm8NPPNK9QcEQ3q+ERa5M6eM72PpF93g2p5cjKgyzzfoIV09Zb/LJ2aW2g\n" +
                "QwIDAQAB\n" +
                "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
    }

    public static PrivateKey getPrivateKeyFromString(String key) throws GeneralSecurityException {
        String privateKeyPEM = key;
        privateKeyPEM = privateKeyPEM.replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
        privateKeyPEM = privateKeyPEM.replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
        privateKeyPEM = privateKeyPEM.replaceAll("[\\r\\n]+", "");
        byte[] encoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(privateKeyPEM);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(encoded);
        PrivateKey privKey = (PrivateKey) kf.generatePrivate(keySpec);
        return privKey;
    }

    public static PublicKey getPublicKeyFromString(String key) throws GeneralSecurityException {
        String publicKeyPEM = key;
        publicKeyPEM = publicKeyPEM.replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----", "");
        publicKeyPEM = publicKeyPEM.replace("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "");
        publicKeyPEM = publicKeyPEM.replaceAll("[\\r\\n]+", "");
        byte[] encoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(publicKeyPEM);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PublicKey pubKey = (PublicKey) kf.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(encoded));
        return pubKey;
    }

    private static String loadRsaKeyPemFile(String filename) throws IOException {
        return new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filename)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I understood the question correctly, the OPs are concerned with why their ciphertext cannot be decrypted and not with how RSA decryption/encryption with OAEP works in principle. The OPs themselves have posted a working code. To answer this question, it is probably more important to know how exactly the ciphertext of the OPs has been encrypted. But maybe I misunderstand the question.

Comment: @Topaco: you are right in your understanding (I fully agree) but as the OP wrote "This is a code we got online" I thought it could be an idea to post a full **working** code instead of searching the error .

Comment: The (online) code posted by the OPs also works. But OK, your code is more detailed and maybe it helps the OPs to identify their issues.